# RGBDSlam_v2 error with rosdep install

Tags: ros, rosdep, rgbdslam-v2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey so I'm running hydro compiled from source on XUbuntu 13.10 ARM for Odroid and I've been smashing my head against an error for a while now. When I try to run rosdep install rgbdslam after downloading all the right stuff based on this guide
http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/, I get this error

```
odroid@odroid:~/rgbdslam_catkin_ws$ rosdep install rgbdslam
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rgbdslam: No definition of [message_runtime] for OS version [saucy]
```

Does anybody know why this might be or how to fix it? I've tried just passing the step and just using catkin_make, but there are a lot of dependencies that I don't know how to acquire, so I'd like to get this to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175227/rgbdslam_v2-error-with-rosdep-install/) by [4dahalibut](https://answers.ros.org/users/19021/4dahalibut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-06-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdep command you tried only works for debian installs. It checks for all packages that are (recusrive) dependencies of `rgbdslam` if they are installed from `apt` and if not, tries to install them. Since they are not available on saucy, the command fails.

For from-source installs you need to specify the `--ignore-src` option to make rosdep ignore packages found in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, i.e. the ones in your from-source base install:

```
rosdep install -i rgbdslam
```

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4dahalibut](https://answers.ros.org/users/19021/4dahalibut/) on 2014-06-30**:
This worked, thanks.